# Algorithm to find all possible base26 numbers of a 32-bit cropped value

Tags: algorithms

I have following formula:

`base26value = 26(26(26(26(26(26a + b) + c) + d) + e) + f) + g`

The variables `a..g` have a range between 0..25 and were entered by an user during the runtime of a program.

Accidently, the variable `base26value` was saved as 32-bit integer, so actually the formula I used is following:

`base26value = (26(26(26(26(26(26a + b) + c) + d) + e) + f) + g) mod (2^32)`

So, the original base26 number is not recoverable unambiguous anymore.

However, I am looking for an algorithm which can list all possible combinations of the `a..g` variables which lead to a given `base26value` value:

`base26value = 26(26(26(26(26(26(26a + b) + c) + d) + e) + f) + g) mod (2^32)
             = 26(26(26(26(26(26(26a' + b') + c') + d') + e') + f') + g') mod (2^32)
             = 26(26(26(26(26(26(26a'' + b'') + c'') + d'') + e'') + f'') + g'') mod (2^32)
             = ...`

I have thought a long time about it but I didn't find any solution to find all possible values for `a'..g'`, `a''..g''`, `a'''..g'''` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(26*(26*(26*(26*(26*(26*25+25)+25)+25)+25)+25)+25)=8031810175$$

$$2*(2^{32}-1)=8589934590>\mbox{the above}$$

Hence if the number recorded is $(26(26(26(26(26(26a + b) + c) + d) + e) + f) + g)=M$ mod $2^{32}-1$, and really $(26(26(26(26(26(26a + b) + c) + d) + e) + f) + g)=N$, the possibilities are:

$$N=M \mbox{ or } N=M+2^{32}-1$$

Then I guess you know that you can retrieve the base-$26$ number $abcdefg$ from N by repeated division by 26 and recording of remainders.

Comment: The base26 number has 7 digits (`a..g`). My calculation was `26^7-1 = 8031810175{base10} = ZZZZZZZ{base26}` and `2^32-1 = 4294967295{base10}` , so there seems to be a clipping.

Comment: yeah sorry, correcting...

Comment: Thank you very much. I was a bit confused with the single variables `a..g`, so that I didn't saw how easy it is when I view it as whole number. (But the value which needs to be added is `2^32` and not `2^32-1`)

Comment: Well your question definitely said it was stored mod $2^{32}-1$

Comment: 32-bit means `2^32-1` is the upper border value, but it means a modulo of `2^32`.

Answer (score 1):

As $26^7/2^{32} \approx 1.87$, there will be only one set of $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ for about$13\%$ of the values and two sets for all the rest.  They will be related by $abcdefg_{26}=a'b'c'd'e'f'g'_{26} + 2^{32}=a'b'c'd'e'f'g'_{26}+13:23:12:17:11:23:22_{26}$
It corresponds to putting a leading $1$ in front of the base $2$ representation of the primed values.  Remember to carry when doing the addition.